# How do I get a bottom to top build in animation with Keynote?

Tags: keynote, animation

I am writing a slide with Maslow's Hierarchy on it, and I want to build in from bottom to top.  How do I change the animation order or otherwise make it build in from the bottom of the pyramid, on the bottom of the page, to the top of the pyramid, on the top of the page.

I know how to do it in PowerPoint or use LibreOffice but the inspector won't let me break apart the build in ordering.

Answer (score 1):

If each section of the pyramid is a separate object then this shouldn't be too difficult to do via the inspector. All you need to do is select each object one at a time and add an entrance effect to it. Then in the animation tab of the inspector you can click on "More Options" (in the same place that the "Close Drawer" button is in the screenshot below)  and a drawer will slide out that allows you to change the sequence of animations (by dragging and dropping). Here's a screenshot of a simple sequence involving three objects.

[image]

It is also possible to control the animation of text boxes in a similar fashion (since they can be selected as individual objects). Additionally one can also set bulleted text to come in one bullet at a time with the following settings:

[image]

So instead of setting the "Delivery" occur "All at Once," change it to "By Paragraph."

Comment: Is there a way to do it with one text block?  Bullet by Bullet?

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. Is that the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: But How do I make it show 4, then 3, then 2, then 1?  The picture you show has it in order.  Is there any way without the one object per reveal yak shaving?

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to accomplish that is to do it one object at a time (logically it would seem that you could just set it to build from "last" to "first," however this is not an option).